# How to avoid mongo from returning duplicated documents by iterating a cursor in a constantly updated big collection?

Tags: mongodb

**Context**

I have a big collection with millions of documents which is constantly updated with production workload. When performing a query, I have noticed that a document can be returned multiple times; My workload tries to migrate the documents to a SQL system which is set to allow unique row ids, hence it crashes.

**Problem**

Because the collection is so big and lots of users are updating it after the query is started, iterating over the cursor's result may give me documents with the same id (old and updated version).

**What I'v tried**

```
const cursor = db.collection.find(query, {snapshot: true});
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   const doc = cursor.next();
   // do some stuff
}
```

Based on old documentation for the mongo driver (I'm using nodejs but this is applicable to any official mongodb driver), there is an option called `snapshot` which is said to avoid what is happening to me. Sadly, the driver returns an error indicating that this option does not exists (It was deprecated).

**Question**

Is there a way to iterate through the documents of a collection in a safe fashion that I don't get the same document twice?

I only see a viable option with aggregation pipeline, but I want to explore other options with standard queries.

Comment: Transaction + snapshot read concern should do it.

Comment: @D.SM I'm curious. How can this be performed?

Comment: Start a transaction with snapshot read concern, read in the transaction.

Comment: @D.SM Looking at the docs, it says that it doesn't support sharded collections. Let alone performance issues compared with index hint. But I will try it some day. Thanks for the info

Comment: What doesn't support according to which docs?

Comment: You can only use read concern "local" or "majority" for the transaction. If you use read concern "snapshot", the transaction errors and aborts.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-snapshot/
@D.SM

Comment: The link you posted says snapshot is a valid read concern option.

Comment: You can't use it though if you disabled majority read concern because then MVCC doesn't exist. I'm not sure where you are going with this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from a [mongo changelog page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/):

MongoDB 3.6.1 deprecates the snapshot query option.

For MMAPv1, use hint() on the { _id: 1} index instead to prevent a cursor from returning a document more than once if an intervening write operation results in a move of the document.

For other storage engines, use hint() with { $natural : 1 } instead.

So, from my code example:

```
const cursor = db.collection.find(query).hint({$natural: 1});
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   const doc = cursor.next();
   // do some stuff
}
```